# Show alert with Indeterminate progress indicator Nokia Full Touch j2me

Tags: java-me, spinner, nokia, midp, lcdui

Does anyone know how to show a spinner for progress bar in a j2me alert?

Here is my piece of code so far:

```
loadingDialog = new Alert("Please Wait","Please Wait.",null,AlertType.INFO);
Gauge gau = new Gauge( null, false,
            Gauge.INDEFINITE,
            Gauge.CONTINUOUS_RUNNING );

loadingDialog.setIndicator(gau);
loadingDialog.setTimeout(500000);
displays.setCurrent(loadingDialog);
```

I am getting a horizontal line (like a slider). What I want is a spinner in place of it.
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Full_Touch/ui-components/progress-indication.html

The second image (labelled non interactive gauge) of the link is what I am looking for:

[image]

Comment: show the snippet of the code where you need help

Comment: sorry for not providing the code. But I dont know how it wil help the situation.

Answer (score 1):

The way how you create Gauge looks about right, in accordance with instructions given at Nokia page you refer as well as with Gauge API javadocs ([available online](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Gauge.html)):

> `CONTINUOUS_RUNNING`
>      The value representing the continuous-running state of a non-interactive Gauge with indefinite range.
>   ...
>   `INDEFINITE`
>      A special value used for the maximum value in order to indicate that the Gauge has indefinite range.

Explanation at Nokia page (somewhat vague) suggests the most likely reason for the issue you describe is that Nokia shows spinner only in forms, not in alerts:

> - Indefinite gauge in Java Form uses spinner.
>   - An Alert uses a "barber shop roll" (animated bar of fixed length).

The way to test above assumption is to put Gauge like yours into the `Form` instead of `Alert` and see how device / emulator displays it.

If Form shows spinner, then the most straightforward workaround is to use Form instead of Alert. In this case, since Form lack "dismissal" feature provided by Alert, you would have to implement it yourself - eg by using `TimerTask` to schedule form replacement with previous screen.

Answer (score -1):

Hehehe, the clue is in the link you gave --

> Java Alerts do not use spinners due to layout constraints.

So it's not possible!

Comment: Please check out some real life applications or any nokia app which uses in app purchase. You will see that it works.

Comment: So the documentation is incorrect?  Please give precise examples of such apps that display the spinner on Nokia touch devices?  Also be aware that if the app is using in-app purchase then the `Alert` won't be initiated from user code...  it will be initiated from the native API which can do things user code can't.